# Dell Inspiron 5423 CPU low-power state Non-Dell Power Adapter

Tags: dell, laptop, power-management, cpufreq

So I've been trying for hours now to get the CPU out of the low power state.
The Processor is a Dual-Core with HT @1.8ghz however because im not using a Dell Adapter its missing the protocol chip that sends the signal to the BIOS. Which means all cores are stuck at 800mhz. Found on the net that the BIOS only "Suggests" what speed the CPU should run at and by making the Linux Kernel ignore APCI calls will allow the CPU to run at full speed.
Currently got the latest install of Ubuntu 64-bit 14.04.3

Ive tried editing Grub with the following

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="processor.ignore_ppc=1"
```

as well as adding it to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` followed by

```
sudo update-grub && sudo reboot
```

I've tried changing the `/sys/module/processor/parameters/ignore_ppc` to 1, still did nothing after reboot. I tried changing the `scaling_max_freq` in `cpu0-3` `@1800000` and got a access denied from editing in `sudo nano`.

Theres another fix involving changing the `BIOS_limit` file in `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/` but the file does not exist and I'm unable to create a file in that directory.

The laptops function is to run BOINC Seti@home until it dies pretty much and that's when i noticed it running at 800mhz on all 4 cores.

In case anyone is wondering the adapter I'm using is the same voltage and amp rating as the Dell adapter.

Have i missed anything?

Comment: which cpu frequency scaling driver are you using? `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver` Which frequency scaling governor are you using? `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor` .

Comment: The current scaling driver is Intel_pstate and the scaling_governor is set to performance

Comment: Try the acpi-cpufreq scaling driver. `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="processor.ignore_ppc=1 intel_pstate=disable"` and note that then the `bios_limit` setting will then be present also.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the help Doug Smythies. Adding intel_pstate=disable worked like a charm its now running 1.8ghz per core. Thanks

Comment: Great. Note that the acpi-cpufreq driver reports the cpu frequency that was asked for, not what you actually get. You need to use turbostat to know for sure or use some sort of timed loop where you know how long it should take as a function of CPU frequency. The intel_pstate driver reports the actual frequency over the last sample interval.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, BIOS should contain a secure check to be sure you're using an original power adapter that you can turn off

Comment: You can only suppress the warnings that appear on the POST screen unfortunately you can not disable it completely. Ive even searched around for a custom BIOS with this security feature removed but it seems its not of a priority.

Comment: try to follow this guide:
http://techmonks.net/bypassing-the-dell-unrecognized-adapter-issue/